# how can I fetch data from a text file and convert into a 2d array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, svelte

I have a text file text.dta in my static folder. The content is like this:

1994 John
2009 Sally
1984 George

I want to fetch this and end up with an array of items which has 2 dimensions, one for the year and one for the name, so end up with items[0,0] = 1994, Items[0,1] = "John"
items[1,0] = 2009, items[1,1] = "Sally"
items[2,0] = 1984, items[2,1] = "George"
What I am getting with the code below is a single dimension array with all items together, as in a text file.

```
<script>
    let text;
    let items = [];
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    onMount(() => {
        loadItems();
    });

    const loadItems = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('data.txt');
    text = await response.text();
    items = text.split('\n\n');
    };
</script>

{#each items as item, index}
    <p>{item}</p>
{/each}
```

What I get is and items array and in console this looks like:
array(0)
"1994 John/r/n2009 Sally/r/n1984 George"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vite, you can [import the file content as a raw string](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#importing-asset-as-string), but using `fetch()` as you do will work too.

Using `text.split('/r/n')` (you seem to be on Windows, so use `/r/n` for line breaks), you would end up with an array looking like this:

```js
const items = [
    "1994 John",
    "2009 Sally",
    "1984 George",
]
```

For each item here, you also need to call `split(" ")` on the item to separate the year from the name.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I thought maybe I could read in the text file line by line and separate the data items but I get the entire file and as you say I then have to  process that to separate out the fields. I will post an answer with the code since I dont think I can add the code here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As Peppe said, the fetch brings the entire file in raw ready to process. Here is what I came up with ..

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let data;
    //
    onMount(async () => {
        // fetch the data.txt file & store in data
        const response = await fetch('data.txt');
        data = await response.text();
        //
        // process data - I wanted to strip out cr/lf characters and split the content by ' ' (a separator between the number and name). Then I wanted to sort by number.
        //
        let lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
        let items = lines.map((line) => {
            let [number, name] = line.split(' ');
            return { number: +number, name };
        });
        items.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);

        // ... 
        // whatever other processing you need
        // ...
    
    })
</script>
<h1> The processed data looks like this: </h1>
<h2> {items] </h2>
```